# Offline install and use of angular/material2-docs-content

Tags: material-design, angular-material2

I am working almost of time offline. 
I want to have an offline copy of the site https://material.angular.io/. 
I searched the net for a solution.

I downloaded the package **angular/material2-docs-content** from GitHub but I don't know how to use it. 
There's no **index.html** file.

Can anyone help me. I am new in the nodeJS and npm worlds

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow these steps:**

1. Clone the [repository](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io) with `git clone https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io.git` (or just download the [ZIP](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/archive/master.zip))
2. open the project directory
3. open a terminal in this folder and run: `npm install`
4. Run `ng serve`

Now the docs should be accessible at http://localhost:4200 in your browser.

---

*Info*: If you get the error `Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not an array type or a string type.`:

5. go to `src/app/shared/table-of-contents/table-of-contents.ts`
6. in line 105: replace

`for (const header of headers) {`

with

```
for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    let header: any = headers[i];`
```

Save the file and now it should work!

Comment: Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url

Comment: Philipp, Do you know why the NodeListOf error shows up? Are NodeLists only iterable in certain versions of node? Or is it a typescript thing?

Comment: @Will: I'm not sure, there are some issues in the repo of typescript, it may be related to it

Comment: I am using node.js v6.11.2 LTS and the lastest version of git v2.14.1 on Windows 10 machine.